# Fastest data access in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm looking for a way to store data persistently which would take the least time to access when required.
Are there any specific classes I should use?

I've been using  Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings, but I'm not sure if this is the best method.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specific use case. If LocalSettings works for your data then it is probably the best.

If you need more complicated data than will fit in settings then you may want to use a database such as SQLite.

Loading a file and parsing it yourself will probably be slower (especially if you use the brokered runtime classes: you can read local data more directly with native file system API, but not directly from managed code).

If you can predict which data the user will need then you can load it and cache it ahead of time.